# How to update a variable after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I just can't get my head around on how can I click a button and pass a different dataset to a variable in order to dynamically update my Chart.js graph after I press a specific button. I come from python and started to learn js only recently and such code usually works in python. Please see my code

```
<div id="parentElementID">
    <button type="button" id="1">Button1</button>
    <button type="button" id="2">Button2</button>
    <button type="button" id="3">Button3</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spins15 = [1, 1, 1]
    //These should update the value of a variable on click. But apparently they don't
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#1').click(function(){
            spins15=[15, 25, 35];
            });
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#2').click(function(){
            spins15=[25, 31, 24];
            });
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#3').click(function(){
            spins15=[50, 11, 25];
            });
        });
    //Chart.js part
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        };

    let someChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'bar',
        data:{
            labels:['0', '32', '15'],

            datasets:[{
                label:'Some chart',
                //This variable below should be updated in order to update the barchart
                data:spins15
            }]
        },
        options:options
    });

    //

</script>
```

Comment: You need to call `someChart.update();`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
chart.data.labels.push(label);
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(data);
});
chart.update();}

function removeData(chart) {
chart.data.labels.pop();
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.pop();
});
chart.update();}
```

[Source: Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the object method **.update()**, every time you change the data, in order to update the graph visualisation. 
Take a look at the documentation of the Chartjs library: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html.

Answer (score 0):

Original Docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig

Sample:

```
 $('#1').click(function () {
    spins15 = [15, 25, 35];
    someChart.data.datasets[0] = spin;
    someChart.update();
});
```